# Query for upcoming birthdays using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails v4 with MongoDB. I have a column `'dob` date type, I want to find upcoming birthdays? Please help.

I have tried like below but no use:

```
scope :upcoming_birthdays, -> 
      { 
         where({"dob.strftime('%m').lte" => 
              (Date.today+3.days).month, 
              "dob.strftime('%d').lte" =>(Date.today+3.days).day}) 
      }
```

Comment: what kind of error do you get? are you on mongoid?

Comment: Can't you just pass in a range of birthdays? What format are the birthdays stored in the database as? logically: `birthday >= today and birthday < three_days_from_now`

Comment: And the **other point** is you use your language **native date objects** not strings. If you have strings in your document fields, then you should change them to be dates.

Comment: Hi WiredPrairie, I have created dob as a date fomat, I have to show upcoming birthdays like facebook. I have to compare month and date not the year.

Answer (score 0):

In mongo you could use the aggregation framework for that

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {_id: 1, month: {$month: '$dob'}, day: {$dayOfMonth: '$dob'}}},
  {$match: {month: 9, day: 14}} ])
```

with the actual `$match` criteria you want.

So you should pump your scope to do that or implement a class method instead of a scope.

Comment: The question asked for a **date range** which this does not do. Also this sort of matching only useful where you absolutely need to. Once you have **projected** your indexes can no longer be used through the rest of the pipeline. This is why you would $match with a native date range **first**.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution , but it has to re factor. Here I am getting today and next two days birthday user details.

```
pro = {:day => {:$dayOfMonth => '$dob'}, :month => {:$month => '$dob'}, :year => {:$year => '$dob'} } 
today = Date.today
birth_dates = [today.day, (today+1.day).day, (today+2.days).day ]
birth_months = [today.month, (today+1.day).month, (today+2.days).month ].uniq
mat = {day: { '$in' => birth_dates } , month: { '$in' => birth_months } }
uids = User.collection.aggregate([{:$project => pro }, {:$match =>  mat  }]).map{ |h| h["_id"] }
birth_users = User.find(uids, :order => :dob)
```

But the problem is , here dob field is optional so it causing below error

failed with error 16006: exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date

Any one suggest please.

Thanks,
Prasad

Comment: Got the answer =>  User.collection.aggregate([ { :$match => {:dob => { :$exists=> true} }},{:$project => pro }] )